# Show emails in queue

Tags: mandrill

I use free account `mandrillapp`. Now I've exceeded the limit (more than 25 mail in hour).

Can I see all email which now is in backlog of `mandrillapp`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mandrill doesn't have a way to view emails in your backlog directly. You can look at your recent API calls though, to see what messages were queued. The first section in this article has info on how to view API logs: https://mandrill.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/213530577-SMTP-Troubleshooting-Tips

Comment: Thanks! It's almost what I need.